# Checking for and Potential Malware When Downloading a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, malware, virus

I am trying to enable users on a web application to download HTML strings of any URLs using ASP.NET MVC. I know that it would be very easy to download a page using the following code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ())
{
    string code= client.DownloadString(URL);
    //...
}
```

Now the question is whether I need to check the request for any possible or potential attacks or malwares ot etc?

P.S: How would I know what file type I am getting? If it is let's say an image file, the response (somewhere I don't know) should have the content-type. Where is it?

Comment: "Malware" or "virus"? That's a task best left for those in the anti-malware / virus expertise. Just because you can restrict/set some `content-type` doesn't mean you are "checking for malware or virus" in any way.

Comment: Could you tell me how to check the content-type?

Comment: you could implement the virus total suggestion below, and also check with URL reputation sites such as https://sitereview.bluecoat.com/sitereview.jsp. For analysis of whether malware is being passed to the user, you should look at a robust commercial product and not reinvent the wheel. Costs money though, such is life.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a md5 hash of a file to [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/) and see if a file is a known virus.

Comment: I am suggesting I should be doing that or not!? Because I am only downloading the string.

Comment: That's not the answer to the question I asked.